# Slowness in TFS integration

Tags: tfs

We are migrating 60 Thousand workitems from TFS 2010 environment to 2012 environment using the TFS Integration tool. In the test environment is took very less time as less traffic was there , but in production environment it is taking more than 2 weeks as calculated by the current speed it is going in.

Is there anything we can do to speed up the migration ?

How does the tool works to migrate these workitems ?

Comment: In your scenario my first suspicion would be, that the database growth configuration for your backing SQL database is set to a very small amount so that your process is constantly interrupted because the db needs to resize.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new query in TFS Integration Tool to reduce the amount of work items to be migrated at one time.